# Stopping skew of the object while using camera.lookat() in three.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I have made this short code to move a object randomly on the screen. I used camera.lookat(). But while using it I observed that when the model/object moves to the sides of the screen, in order to look at the camera it changes its shape a little. In a way one can say that it skews a little.

I wanted to used camera.lookat() without this skewing of the object. I have been trying for a while now but couldn't figure out a way to do it. Can anyone help me out here please. Here is my code:

## EDIT

while running code snippet here you may find a error footer here. It's because of unavailability of tween.js cdn. Wait for some time after clicking on "run snippet" here and you will see a tower moving here and there.

My JS:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xff0000, .5);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
light1.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
scene.add(light1);

var light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
light2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
scene.add(light2);

camera.position.z = 20;


var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = true;
loader.load('https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf', function(gltf) {


  cube = gltf.scene;
  //    gltf.scene.position.y -= 15;
  //    gltf.scene.position.x -= 24;
  //    gltf.scene.lookAt(camera.position);
  gltf.scene.position.set(-40, 0, -3.75);
  gltf.scene.scale.set(0.4, 0.4, 0.4);
  //     gltf.scene.rotation.y += 0.6;
  //     gltf.scene.rotation.z -= 0.3;

  scene.add(gltf.scene);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  maketween();

});

















//// Setup the animation loop.
function animate(time) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  TWEEN.update(time);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);




function maketween() {
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 57) - 28;
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 23) - 10;
  var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({
      x: cube.position.x,
      y: cube.position.y,
      z: cube.position.z
    }) // Create a new tween that modifies 'coords'.
    .to({
      x: randomX,
      y: randomY,
      z: 0
    }, 1000) // Move to (300, 200) in 1 second.
    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out) // Use an easing function to make the animation smooth.
    .repeat(0)
    .onUpdate(function(object) {

      //                      console.log("tween",randomX,randomY,object.x);
      if (object.x == randomX || object.x == 0) {

        var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 57) - 28;
        var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 23) - 10;
        //                       console.log("*",randomX,randomY);

      } else {

        cube.position.x = object.x;
        cube.position.y = object.y;
      }
      cube.lookAt(camera.position);



    }).onComplete(() => {
      //                   console.log("tween stopped");
      maketween();


    });

  tween.chain(tween);
  tween.start();

}



















//BELOW THIS POINT IS TWEEN.JS (NOT MY CODE)



(function (global, factory) {
 typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
 typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
 (global.TWEEN = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

 var version = '18.4.2';

 /**
  * Tween.js - Licensed under the MIT license
  * https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js
  * ----------------------------------------------
  *
  * See https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/graphs/contributors for the full list of contributors.
  * Thank you all, you're awesome!
  */


 var _Group = function () {
  this._tweens = {};
  this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate = {};
 };

 _Group.prototype = {
  getAll: function () {

   return Object.keys(this._tweens).map(function (tweenId) {
    return this._tweens[tweenId];
   }.bind(this));

  },

  removeAll: function () {

   this._tweens = {};

  },

  add: function (tween) {

   this._tweens[tween.getId()] = tween;
   this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate[tween.getId()] = tween;

  },

  remove: function (tween) {

   delete this._tweens[tween.getId()];
   delete this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate[tween.getId()];

  },

  update: function (time, preserve) {

   var tweenIds = Object.keys(this._tweens);

   if (tweenIds.length === 0) {
    return false;
   }

   time = time !== undefined ? time : TWEEN.now();

   // Tweens are updated in "batches". If you add a new tween during an
   // update, then the new tween will be updated in the next batch.
   // If you remove a tween during an update, it may or may not be updated.
   // However, if the removed tween was added during the current batch,
   // then it will not be updated.
   while (tweenIds.length > 0) {
    this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < tweenIds.length; i++) {

     var tween = this._tweens[tweenIds[i]];

     if (tween && tween.update(time) === false) {
      tween._isPlaying = false;

      if (!preserve) {
       delete this._tweens[tweenIds[i]];
      }
     }
    }

    tweenIds = Object.keys(this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate);
   }

   return true;

  }
 };

 var TWEEN = new _Group();

 TWEEN.Group = _Group;
 TWEEN._nextId = 0;
 TWEEN.nextId = function () {
  return TWEEN._nextId++;
 };


 // Include a performance.now polyfill.
 // In node.js, use process.hrtime.
 if (typeof (self) === 'undefined' && typeof (process) !== 'undefined' && process.hrtime) {
  TWEEN.now = function () {
   var time = process.hrtime();

   // Convert [seconds, nanoseconds] to milliseconds.
   return time[0] * 1000 + time[1] / 1000000;
  };
 }
 // In a browser, use self.performance.now if it is available.
 else if (typeof (self) !== 'undefined' &&
          self.performance !== undefined &&
    self.performance.now !== undefined) {
  // This must be bound, because directly assigning this function
  // leads to an invocation exception in Chrome.
  TWEEN.now = self.performance.now.bind(self.performance);
 }
 // Use Date.now if it is available.
 else if (Date.now !== undefined) {
  TWEEN.now = Date.now;
 }
 // Otherwise, use 'new Date().getTime()'.
 else {
  TWEEN.now = function () {
   return new Date().getTime();
  };
 }


 TWEEN.Tween = function (object, group) {
  this._isPaused = false;
  this._pauseStart = null;
  this._object = object;
  this._valuesStart = {};
  this._valuesEnd = {};
  this._valuesStartRepeat = {};
  this._duration = 1000;
  this._repeat = 0;
  this._repeatDelayTime = undefined;
  this._yoyo = false;
  this._isPlaying = false;
  this._reversed = false;
  this._delayTime = 0;
  this._startTime = null;
  this._easingFunction = TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None;
  this._interpolationFunction = TWEEN.Interpolation.Linear;
  this._chainedTweens = [];
  this._onStartCallback = null;
  this._onStartCallbackFired = false;
  this._onUpdateCallback = null;
  this._onRepeatCallback = null;
  this._onCompleteCallback = null;
  this._onStopCallback = null;
  this._group = group || TWEEN;
  this._id = TWEEN.nextId();

 };

 TWEEN.Tween.prototype = {
  getId: function () {
   return this._id;
  },

  isPlaying: function () {
   return this._isPlaying;
  },

  isPaused: function () {
   return this._isPaused;
  },

  to: function (properties, duration) {

   this._valuesEnd = Object.create(properties);

   if (duration !== undefined) {
    this._duration = duration;
   }

   return this;

  },

  duration: function duration(d) {
   this._duration = d;
   return this;
  },

  start: function (time) {

   this._group.add(this);

   this._isPlaying = true;

   this._isPaused = false;

   this._onStartCallbackFired = false;

   this._startTime = time !== undefined ? typeof time === 'string' ? TWEEN.now() + parseFloat(time) : time : TWEEN.now();
   this._startTime += this._delayTime;

   for (var property in this._valuesEnd) {

    // Check if an Array was provided as property value
    if (this._valuesEnd[property] instanceof Array) {

     if (this._valuesEnd[property].length === 0) {
      continue;
     }

     // Create a local copy of the Array with the start value at the front
     this._valuesEnd[property] = [this._object[property]].concat(this._valuesEnd[property]);

    }

    // If `to()` specifies a property that doesn't exist in the source object,
    // we should not set that property in the object
    if (this._object[property] === undefined) {
     continue;
    }

    // Save the starting value, but only once.
    if (typeof(this._valuesStart[property]) === 'undefined') {
     this._valuesStart[property] = this._object[property];
    }

    if ((this._valuesStart[property] instanceof Array) === false) {
     this._valuesStart[property] *= 1.0; // Ensures we're using numbers, not strings
    }

    this._valuesStartRepeat[property] = this._valuesStart[property] || 0;

   }

   return this;

  },

  stop: function () {

   if (!this._isPlaying) {
    return this;
   }

   this._group.remove(this);

   this._isPlaying = false;

   this._isPaused = false;

   if (this._onStopCallback !== null) {
    this._onStopCallback(this._object);
   }

   this.stopChainedTweens();
   return this;

  },

  end: function () {

   this.update(Infinity);
   return this;

  },

  pause: function(time) {

   if (this._isPaused || !this._isPlaying) {
    return this;
   }

   this._isPaused = true;

   this._pauseStart = time === undefined ? TWEEN.now() : time;

   this._group.remove(this);

   return this;

  },

  resume: function(time) {

   if (!this._isPaused || !this._isPlaying) {
    return this;
   }

   this._isPaused = false;

   this._startTime += (time === undefined ? TWEEN.now() : time)
    - this._pauseStart;

   this._pauseStart = 0;

   this._group.add(this);

   return this;

  },

  stopChainedTweens: function () {

   for (var i = 0, numChainedTweens = this._chainedTweens.length; i < numChainedTweens; i++) {
    this._chainedTweens[i].stop();
   }

  },

  group: function (group) {
   this._group = group;
   return this;
  },

  delay: function (amount) {

   this._delayTime = amount;
   return this;

  },

  repeat: function (times) {

   this._repeat = times;
   return this;

  },

  repeatDelay: function (amount) {

   this._repeatDelayTime = amount;
   return this;

  },

  yoyo: function (yoyo) {

   this._yoyo = yoyo;
   return this;

  },

  easing: function (easingFunction) {

   this._easingFunction = easingFunction;
   return this;

  },

  interpolation: function (interpolationFunction) {

   this._interpolationFunction = interpolationFunction;
   return this;

  },

  chain: function () {

   this._chainedTweens = arguments;
   return this;

  },

  onStart: function (callback) {

   this._onStartCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  onUpdate: function (callback) {

   this._onUpdateCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  onRepeat: function onRepeat(callback) {

   this._onRepeatCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  onComplete: function (callback) {

   this._onCompleteCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  onStop: function (callback) {

   this._onStopCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  update: function (time) {

   var property;
   var elapsed;
   var value;

   if (time < this._startTime) {
    return true;
   }

   if (this._onStartCallbackFired === false) {

    if (this._onStartCallback !== null) {
     this._onStartCallback(this._object);
    }

    this._onStartCallbackFired = true;
   }

   elapsed = (time - this._startTime) / this._duration;
   elapsed = (this._duration === 0 || elapsed > 1) ? 1 : elapsed;

   value = this._easingFunction(elapsed);

   for (property in this._valuesEnd) {

    // Don't update properties that do not exist in the source object
    if (this._valuesStart[property] === undefined) {
     continue;
    }

    var start = this._valuesStart[property] || 0;
    var end = this._valuesEnd[property];

    if (end instanceof Array) {

     this._object[property] = this._interpolationFunction(end, value);

    } else {

     // Parses relative end values with start as base (e.g.: +10, -3)
     if (typeof (end) === 'string') {

      if (end.charAt(0) === '+' || end.charAt(0) === '-') {
       end = start + parseFloat(end);
      } else {
       end = parseFloat(end);
      }
     }

     // Protect against non numeric properties.
     if (typeof (end) === 'number') {
      this._object[property] = start + (end - start) * value;
     }

    }

   }

   if (this._onUpdateCallback !== null) {
    this._onUpdateCallback(this._object, elapsed);
   }

   if (elapsed === 1) {

    if (this._repeat > 0) {

     if (isFinite(this._repeat)) {
      this._repeat--;
     }

     // Reassign starting values, restart by making startTime = now
     for (property in this._valuesStartRepeat) {

      if (typeof (this._valuesEnd[property]) === 'string') {
       this._valuesStartRepeat[property] = this._valuesStartRepeat[property] + parseFloat(this._valuesEnd[property]);
      }

      if (this._yoyo) {
       var tmp = this._valuesStartRepeat[property];

       this._valuesStartRepeat[property] = this._valuesEnd[property];
       this._valuesEnd[property] = tmp;
      }

      this._valuesStart[property] = this._valuesStartRepeat[property];

     }

     if (this._yoyo) {
      this._reversed = !this._reversed;
     }

     if (this._repeatDelayTime !== undefined) {
      this._startTime = time + this._repeatDelayTime;
     } else {
      this._startTime = time + this._delayTime;
     }

     if (this._onRepeatCallback !== null) {
      this._onRepeatCallback(this._object);
     }

     return true;

    } else {

     if (this._onCompleteCallback !== null) {

      this._onCompleteCallback(this._object);
     }

     for (var i = 0, numChainedTweens = this._chainedTweens.length; i < numChainedTweens; i++) {
      // Make the chained tweens start exactly at the time they should,
      // even if the `update()` method was called way past the duration of the tween
      this._chainedTweens[i].start(this._startTime + this._duration);
     }

     return false;

    }

   }

   return true;

  }
 };


 TWEEN.Easing = {

  Linear: {

   None: function (k) {

    return k;

   }

  },

  Quadratic: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k * k;

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return k * (2 - k);

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * k * k;
    }

    return - 0.5 * (--k * (k - 2) - 1);

   }

  },

  Cubic: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k * k * k;

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return --k * k * k + 1;

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * k * k * k;
    }

    return 0.5 * ((k -= 2) * k * k + 2);

   }

  },

  Quartic: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k * k * k * k;

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return 1 - (--k * k * k * k);

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * k * k * k * k;
    }

    return - 0.5 * ((k -= 2) * k * k * k - 2);

   }

  },

  Quintic: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k * k * k * k * k;

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return --k * k * k * k * k + 1;

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * k * k * k * k * k;
    }

    return 0.5 * ((k -= 2) * k * k * k * k + 2);

   }

  },

  Sinusoidal: {

   In: function (k) {

    return 1 - Math.cos(k * Math.PI / 2);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return Math.sin(k * Math.PI / 2);

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    return 0.5 * (1 - Math.cos(Math.PI * k));

   }

  },

  Exponential: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k === 0 ? 0 : Math.pow(1024, k - 1);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return k === 1 ? 1 : 1 - Math.pow(2, - 10 * k);

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if (k === 0) {
     return 0;
    }

    if (k === 1) {
     return 1;
    }

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * Math.pow(1024, k - 1);
    }

    return 0.5 * (- Math.pow(2, - 10 * (k - 1)) + 2);

   }

  },

  Circular: {

   In: function (k) {

    return 1 - Math.sqrt(1 - k * k);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return Math.sqrt(1 - (--k * k));

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return - 0.5 * (Math.sqrt(1 - k * k) - 1);
    }

    return 0.5 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (k -= 2) * k) + 1);

   }

  },

  Elastic: {

   In: function (k) {

    if (k === 0) {
     return 0;
    }

    if (k === 1) {
     return 1;
    }

    return -Math.pow(2, 10 * (k - 1)) * Math.sin((k - 1.1) * 5 * Math.PI);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    if (k === 0) {
     return 0;
    }

    if (k === 1) {
     return 1;
    }

    return Math.pow(2, -10 * k) * Math.sin((k - 0.1) * 5 * Math.PI) + 1;

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if (k === 0) {
     return 0;
    }

    if (k === 1) {
     return 1;
    }

    k *= 2;

    if (k < 1) {
     return -0.5 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (k - 1)) * Math.sin((k - 1.1) * 5 * Math.PI);
    }

    return 0.5 * Math.pow(2, -10 * (k - 1)) * Math.sin((k - 1.1) * 5 * Math.PI) + 1;

   }

  },

  Back: {

   In: function (k) {

    var s = 1.70158;

    return k * k * ((s + 1) * k - s);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    var s = 1.70158;

    return --k * k * ((s + 1) * k + s) + 1;

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    var s = 1.70158 * 1.525;

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * (k * k * ((s + 1) * k - s));
    }

    return 0.5 * ((k -= 2) * k * ((s + 1) * k + s) + 2);

   }

  },

  Bounce: {

   In: function (k) {

    return 1 - TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.Out(1 - k);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    if (k < (1 / 2.75)) {
     return 7.5625 * k * k;
    } else if (k < (2 / 2.75)) {
     return 7.5625 * (k -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * k + 0.75;
    } else if (k < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
     return 7.5625 * (k -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * k + 0.9375;
    } else {
     return 7.5625 * (k -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * k + 0.984375;
    }

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if (k < 0.5) {
     return TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.In(k * 2) * 0.5;
    }

    return TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.Out(k * 2 - 1) * 0.5 + 0.5;

   }

  }

 };

 TWEEN.Interpolation = {

  Linear: function (v, k) {

   var m = v.length - 1;
   var f = m * k;
   var i = Math.floor(f);
   var fn = TWEEN.Interpolation.Utils.Linear;

   if (k < 0) {
    return fn(v[0], v[1], f);
   }

   if (k > 1) {
    return fn(v[m], v[m - 1], m - f);
   }

   return fn(v[i], v[i + 1 > m ? m : i + 1], f - i);

  },

  Bezier: function (v, k) {

   var b = 0;
   var n = v.length - 1;
   var pw = Math.pow;
   var bn = TWEEN.Interpolation.Utils.Bernstein;

   for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    b += pw(1 - k, n - i) * pw(k, i) * v[i] * bn(n, i);
   }

   return b;

  },

  CatmullRom: function (v, k) {

   var m = v.length - 1;
   var f = m * k;
   var i = Math.floor(f);
   var fn = TWEEN.Interpolation.Utils.CatmullRom;

   if (v[0] === v[m]) {

    if (k < 0) {
     i = Math.floor(f = m * (1 + k));
    }

    return fn(v[(i - 1 + m) % m], v[i], v[(i + 1) % m], v[(i + 2) % m], f - i);

   } else {

    if (k < 0) {
     return v[0] - (fn(v[0], v[0], v[1], v[1], -f) - v[0]);
    }

    if (k > 1) {
     return v[m] - (fn(v[m], v[m], v[m - 1], v[m - 1], f - m) - v[m]);
    }

    return fn(v[i ? i - 1 : 0], v[i], v[m < i + 1 ? m : i + 1], v[m < i + 2 ? m : i + 2], f - i);

   }

  },

  Utils: {

   Linear: function (p0, p1, t) {

    return (p1 - p0) * t + p0;

   },

   Bernstein: function (n, i) {

    var fc = TWEEN.Interpolation.Utils.Factorial;

    return fc(n) / fc(i) / fc(n - i);

   },

   Factorial: (function () {

    var a = [1];

    return function (n) {

     var s = 1;

     if (a[n]) {
      return a[n];
     }

     for (var i = n; i > 1; i--) {
      s *= i;
     }

     a[n] = s;
     return s;

    };

   })(),

   CatmullRom: function (p0, p1, p2, p3, t) {

    var v0 = (p2 - p0) * 0.5;
    var v1 = (p3 - p1) * 0.5;
    var t2 = t * t;
    var t3 = t * t2;

    return (2 * p1 - 2 * p2 + v0 + v1) * t3 + (- 3 * p1 + 3 * p2 - 2 * v0 - v1) * t2 + v0 * t + p1;

   }

  }

 };
 TWEEN.version = version;

 return TWEEN;

})));
```

```html
MY HTML:






<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Locate the user</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.tutorialjinni.com/tween.js/18.5.0/Tween.js"></script>











  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    canvas {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>


<script src="js/capture.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Looks like this is just perspective.. The skew should change when you change the fov of the camera. ( the first argument in the THREE.PerspectiveCamera contructor ). Using THREE.OrthographicCamera should eliminate it, but might not be ideal.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is the field of view is wide.

Similar to the way a wide angle lens distorts

[image]

The code had a 75 degree field of view (75 vertically)

Here's a 25 degree field of view. Had to move to the camera back.

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var fieldOfView = 25;
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fieldOfView, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);


var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
renderer.setClearColor(0xff0000, .5);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var light1 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
light1.position.set(0, -70, 100).normalize();
scene.add(light1);

var light2 = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff);
light2.position.set(0, 70, 100).normalize();
scene.add(light2);

camera.position.z = 80;


var loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
loader.crossOrigin = true;
loader.load('https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/assets/34M_17/34M_17.gltf', function(gltf) {


  cube = gltf.scene;
  //    gltf.scene.position.y -= 15;
  //    gltf.scene.position.x -= 24;
  //    gltf.scene.lookAt(camera.position);
  gltf.scene.position.set(-40, 0, -3.75);
  gltf.scene.scale.set(0.4, 0.4, 0.4);
  //     gltf.scene.rotation.y += 0.6;
  //     gltf.scene.rotation.z -= 0.3;

  scene.add(gltf.scene);
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  maketween();

});

















//// Setup the animation loop.
function animate(time) {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  TWEEN.update(time);

  renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);




function maketween() {
  var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 40) - 20;
  var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) - 10;
  var tween = new TWEEN.Tween({
      x: cube.position.x,
      y: cube.position.y,
      z: cube.position.z
    }) // Create a new tween that modifies 'coords'.
    .to({
      x: randomX,
      y: randomY,
      z: 0
    }, 1000) // Move to (300, 200) in 1 second.
    .easing(TWEEN.Easing.Quadratic.Out) // Use an easing function to make the animation smooth.
    .repeat(0)
    .onUpdate(function(object) {

      //                      console.log("tween",randomX,randomY,object.x);
      if (object.x == randomX || object.x == 0) {

        var randomX = Math.floor(Math.random() * 57) - 28;
        var randomY = Math.floor(Math.random() * 23) - 10;
        //                       console.log("*",randomX,randomY);

      } else {

        cube.position.x = object.x;
        cube.position.y = object.y;
      }
      cube.lookAt(camera.position);



    }).onComplete(() => {
      //                   console.log("tween stopped");
      maketween();


    });

  tween.chain(tween);
  tween.start();

}



















//BELOW THIS POINT IS TWEEN.JS (NOT MY CODE)



(function (global, factory) {
 typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module !== 'undefined' ? module.exports = factory() :
 typeof define === 'function' && define.amd ? define(factory) :
 (global.TWEEN = factory());
}(this, (function () { 'use strict';

 var version = '18.4.2';

 /**
  * Tween.js - Licensed under the MIT license
  * https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js
  * ----------------------------------------------
  *
  * See https://github.com/tweenjs/tween.js/graphs/contributors for the full list of contributors.
  * Thank you all, you're awesome!
  */


 var _Group = function () {
  this._tweens = {};
  this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate = {};
 };

 _Group.prototype = {
  getAll: function () {

   return Object.keys(this._tweens).map(function (tweenId) {
    return this._tweens[tweenId];
   }.bind(this));

  },

  removeAll: function () {

   this._tweens = {};

  },

  add: function (tween) {

   this._tweens[tween.getId()] = tween;
   this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate[tween.getId()] = tween;

  },

  remove: function (tween) {

   delete this._tweens[tween.getId()];
   delete this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate[tween.getId()];

  },

  update: function (time, preserve) {

   var tweenIds = Object.keys(this._tweens);

   if (tweenIds.length === 0) {
    return false;
   }

   time = time !== undefined ? time : TWEEN.now();

   // Tweens are updated in "batches". If you add a new tween during an
   // update, then the new tween will be updated in the next batch.
   // If you remove a tween during an update, it may or may not be updated.
   // However, if the removed tween was added during the current batch,
   // then it will not be updated.
   while (tweenIds.length > 0) {
    this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < tweenIds.length; i++) {

     var tween = this._tweens[tweenIds[i]];

     if (tween && tween.update(time) === false) {
      tween._isPlaying = false;

      if (!preserve) {
       delete this._tweens[tweenIds[i]];
      }
     }
    }

    tweenIds = Object.keys(this._tweensAddedDuringUpdate);
   }

   return true;

  }
 };

 var TWEEN = new _Group();

 TWEEN.Group = _Group;
 TWEEN._nextId = 0;
 TWEEN.nextId = function () {
  return TWEEN._nextId++;
 };


 // Include a performance.now polyfill.
 // In node.js, use process.hrtime.
 if (typeof (self) === 'undefined' && typeof (process) !== 'undefined' && process.hrtime) {
  TWEEN.now = function () {
   var time = process.hrtime();

   // Convert [seconds, nanoseconds] to milliseconds.
   return time[0] * 1000 + time[1] / 1000000;
  };
 }
 // In a browser, use self.performance.now if it is available.
 else if (typeof (self) !== 'undefined' &&
          self.performance !== undefined &&
    self.performance.now !== undefined) {
  // This must be bound, because directly assigning this function
  // leads to an invocation exception in Chrome.
  TWEEN.now = self.performance.now.bind(self.performance);
 }
 // Use Date.now if it is available.
 else if (Date.now !== undefined) {
  TWEEN.now = Date.now;
 }
 // Otherwise, use 'new Date().getTime()'.
 else {
  TWEEN.now = function () {
   return new Date().getTime();
  };
 }


 TWEEN.Tween = function (object, group) {
  this._isPaused = false;
  this._pauseStart = null;
  this._object = object;
  this._valuesStart = {};
  this._valuesEnd = {};
  this._valuesStartRepeat = {};
  this._duration = 1000;
  this._repeat = 0;
  this._repeatDelayTime = undefined;
  this._yoyo = false;
  this._isPlaying = false;
  this._reversed = false;
  this._delayTime = 0;
  this._startTime = null;
  this._easingFunction = TWEEN.Easing.Linear.None;
  this._interpolationFunction = TWEEN.Interpolation.Linear;
  this._chainedTweens = [];
  this._onStartCallback = null;
  this._onStartCallbackFired = false;
  this._onUpdateCallback = null;
  this._onRepeatCallback = null;
  this._onCompleteCallback = null;
  this._onStopCallback = null;
  this._group = group || TWEEN;
  this._id = TWEEN.nextId();

 };

 TWEEN.Tween.prototype = {
  getId: function () {
   return this._id;
  },

  isPlaying: function () {
   return this._isPlaying;
  },

  isPaused: function () {
   return this._isPaused;
  },

  to: function (properties, duration) {

   this._valuesEnd = Object.create(properties);

   if (duration !== undefined) {
    this._duration = duration;
   }

   return this;

  },

  duration: function duration(d) {
   this._duration = d;
   return this;
  },

  start: function (time) {

   this._group.add(this);

   this._isPlaying = true;

   this._isPaused = false;

   this._onStartCallbackFired = false;

   this._startTime = time !== undefined ? typeof time === 'string' ? TWEEN.now() + parseFloat(time) : time : TWEEN.now();
   this._startTime += this._delayTime;

   for (var property in this._valuesEnd) {

    // Check if an Array was provided as property value
    if (this._valuesEnd[property] instanceof Array) {

     if (this._valuesEnd[property].length === 0) {
      continue;
     }

     // Create a local copy of the Array with the start value at the front
     this._valuesEnd[property] = [this._object[property]].concat(this._valuesEnd[property]);

    }

    // If `to()` specifies a property that doesn't exist in the source object,
    // we should not set that property in the object
    if (this._object[property] === undefined) {
     continue;
    }

    // Save the starting value, but only once.
    if (typeof(this._valuesStart[property]) === 'undefined') {
     this._valuesStart[property] = this._object[property];
    }

    if ((this._valuesStart[property] instanceof Array) === false) {
     this._valuesStart[property] *= 1.0; // Ensures we're using numbers, not strings
    }

    this._valuesStartRepeat[property] = this._valuesStart[property] || 0;

   }

   return this;

  },

  stop: function () {

   if (!this._isPlaying) {
    return this;
   }

   this._group.remove(this);

   this._isPlaying = false;

   this._isPaused = false;

   if (this._onStopCallback !== null) {
    this._onStopCallback(this._object);
   }

   this.stopChainedTweens();
   return this;

  },

  end: function () {

   this.update(Infinity);
   return this;

  },

  pause: function(time) {

   if (this._isPaused || !this._isPlaying) {
    return this;
   }

   this._isPaused = true;

   this._pauseStart = time === undefined ? TWEEN.now() : time;

   this._group.remove(this);

   return this;

  },

  resume: function(time) {

   if (!this._isPaused || !this._isPlaying) {
    return this;
   }

   this._isPaused = false;

   this._startTime += (time === undefined ? TWEEN.now() : time)
    - this._pauseStart;

   this._pauseStart = 0;

   this._group.add(this);

   return this;

  },

  stopChainedTweens: function () {

   for (var i = 0, numChainedTweens = this._chainedTweens.length; i < numChainedTweens; i++) {
    this._chainedTweens[i].stop();
   }

  },

  group: function (group) {
   this._group = group;
   return this;
  },

  delay: function (amount) {

   this._delayTime = amount;
   return this;

  },

  repeat: function (times) {

   this._repeat = times;
   return this;

  },

  repeatDelay: function (amount) {

   this._repeatDelayTime = amount;
   return this;

  },

  yoyo: function (yoyo) {

   this._yoyo = yoyo;
   return this;

  },

  easing: function (easingFunction) {

   this._easingFunction = easingFunction;
   return this;

  },

  interpolation: function (interpolationFunction) {

   this._interpolationFunction = interpolationFunction;
   return this;

  },

  chain: function () {

   this._chainedTweens = arguments;
   return this;

  },

  onStart: function (callback) {

   this._onStartCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  onUpdate: function (callback) {

   this._onUpdateCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  onRepeat: function onRepeat(callback) {

   this._onRepeatCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  onComplete: function (callback) {

   this._onCompleteCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  onStop: function (callback) {

   this._onStopCallback = callback;
   return this;

  },

  update: function (time) {

   var property;
   var elapsed;
   var value;

   if (time < this._startTime) {
    return true;
   }

   if (this._onStartCallbackFired === false) {

    if (this._onStartCallback !== null) {
     this._onStartCallback(this._object);
    }

    this._onStartCallbackFired = true;
   }

   elapsed = (time - this._startTime) / this._duration;
   elapsed = (this._duration === 0 || elapsed > 1) ? 1 : elapsed;

   value = this._easingFunction(elapsed);

   for (property in this._valuesEnd) {

    // Don't update properties that do not exist in the source object
    if (this._valuesStart[property] === undefined) {
     continue;
    }

    var start = this._valuesStart[property] || 0;
    var end = this._valuesEnd[property];

    if (end instanceof Array) {

     this._object[property] = this._interpolationFunction(end, value);

    } else {

     // Parses relative end values with start as base (e.g.: +10, -3)
     if (typeof (end) === 'string') {

      if (end.charAt(0) === '+' || end.charAt(0) === '-') {
       end = start + parseFloat(end);
      } else {
       end = parseFloat(end);
      }
     }

     // Protect against non numeric properties.
     if (typeof (end) === 'number') {
      this._object[property] = start + (end - start) * value;
     }

    }

   }

   if (this._onUpdateCallback !== null) {
    this._onUpdateCallback(this._object, elapsed);
   }

   if (elapsed === 1) {

    if (this._repeat > 0) {

     if (isFinite(this._repeat)) {
      this._repeat--;
     }

     // Reassign starting values, restart by making startTime = now
     for (property in this._valuesStartRepeat) {

      if (typeof (this._valuesEnd[property]) === 'string') {
       this._valuesStartRepeat[property] = this._valuesStartRepeat[property] + parseFloat(this._valuesEnd[property]);
      }

      if (this._yoyo) {
       var tmp = this._valuesStartRepeat[property];

       this._valuesStartRepeat[property] = this._valuesEnd[property];
       this._valuesEnd[property] = tmp;
      }

      this._valuesStart[property] = this._valuesStartRepeat[property];

     }

     if (this._yoyo) {
      this._reversed = !this._reversed;
     }

     if (this._repeatDelayTime !== undefined) {
      this._startTime = time + this._repeatDelayTime;
     } else {
      this._startTime = time + this._delayTime;
     }

     if (this._onRepeatCallback !== null) {
      this._onRepeatCallback(this._object);
     }

     return true;

    } else {

     if (this._onCompleteCallback !== null) {

      this._onCompleteCallback(this._object);
     }

     for (var i = 0, numChainedTweens = this._chainedTweens.length; i < numChainedTweens; i++) {
      // Make the chained tweens start exactly at the time they should,
      // even if the `update()` method was called way past the duration of the tween
      this._chainedTweens[i].start(this._startTime + this._duration);
     }

     return false;

    }

   }

   return true;

  }
 };


 TWEEN.Easing = {

  Linear: {

   None: function (k) {

    return k;

   }

  },

  Quadratic: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k * k;

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return k * (2 - k);

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * k * k;
    }

    return - 0.5 * (--k * (k - 2) - 1);

   }

  },

  Cubic: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k * k * k;

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return --k * k * k + 1;

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * k * k * k;
    }

    return 0.5 * ((k -= 2) * k * k + 2);

   }

  },

  Quartic: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k * k * k * k;

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return 1 - (--k * k * k * k);

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * k * k * k * k;
    }

    return - 0.5 * ((k -= 2) * k * k * k - 2);

   }

  },

  Quintic: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k * k * k * k * k;

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return --k * k * k * k * k + 1;

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * k * k * k * k * k;
    }

    return 0.5 * ((k -= 2) * k * k * k * k + 2);

   }

  },

  Sinusoidal: {

   In: function (k) {

    return 1 - Math.cos(k * Math.PI / 2);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return Math.sin(k * Math.PI / 2);

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    return 0.5 * (1 - Math.cos(Math.PI * k));

   }

  },

  Exponential: {

   In: function (k) {

    return k === 0 ? 0 : Math.pow(1024, k - 1);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return k === 1 ? 1 : 1 - Math.pow(2, - 10 * k);

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if (k === 0) {
     return 0;
    }

    if (k === 1) {
     return 1;
    }

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * Math.pow(1024, k - 1);
    }

    return 0.5 * (- Math.pow(2, - 10 * (k - 1)) + 2);

   }

  },

  Circular: {

   In: function (k) {

    return 1 - Math.sqrt(1 - k * k);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    return Math.sqrt(1 - (--k * k));

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return - 0.5 * (Math.sqrt(1 - k * k) - 1);
    }

    return 0.5 * (Math.sqrt(1 - (k -= 2) * k) + 1);

   }

  },

  Elastic: {

   In: function (k) {

    if (k === 0) {
     return 0;
    }

    if (k === 1) {
     return 1;
    }

    return -Math.pow(2, 10 * (k - 1)) * Math.sin((k - 1.1) * 5 * Math.PI);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    if (k === 0) {
     return 0;
    }

    if (k === 1) {
     return 1;
    }

    return Math.pow(2, -10 * k) * Math.sin((k - 0.1) * 5 * Math.PI) + 1;

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if (k === 0) {
     return 0;
    }

    if (k === 1) {
     return 1;
    }

    k *= 2;

    if (k < 1) {
     return -0.5 * Math.pow(2, 10 * (k - 1)) * Math.sin((k - 1.1) * 5 * Math.PI);
    }

    return 0.5 * Math.pow(2, -10 * (k - 1)) * Math.sin((k - 1.1) * 5 * Math.PI) + 1;

   }

  },

  Back: {

   In: function (k) {

    var s = 1.70158;

    return k * k * ((s + 1) * k - s);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    var s = 1.70158;

    return --k * k * ((s + 1) * k + s) + 1;

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    var s = 1.70158 * 1.525;

    if ((k *= 2) < 1) {
     return 0.5 * (k * k * ((s + 1) * k - s));
    }

    return 0.5 * ((k -= 2) * k * ((s + 1) * k + s) + 2);

   }

  },

  Bounce: {

   In: function (k) {

    return 1 - TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.Out(1 - k);

   },

   Out: function (k) {

    if (k < (1 / 2.75)) {
     return 7.5625 * k * k;
    } else if (k < (2 / 2.75)) {
     return 7.5625 * (k -= (1.5 / 2.75)) * k + 0.75;
    } else if (k < (2.5 / 2.75)) {
     return 7.5625 * (k -= (2.25 / 2.75)) * k + 0.9375;
    } else {
     return 7.5625 * (k -= (2.625 / 2.75)) * k + 0.984375;
    }

   },

   InOut: function (k) {

    if (k < 0.5) {
     return TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.In(k * 2) * 0.5;
    }

    return TWEEN.Easing.Bounce.Out(k * 2 - 1) * 0.5 + 0.5;

   }

  }

 };

 TWEEN.Interpolation = {

  Linear: function (v, k) {

   var m = v.length - 1;
   var f = m * k;
   var i = Math.floor(f);
   var fn = TWEEN.Interpolation.Utils.Linear;

   if (k < 0) {
    return fn(v[0], v[1], f);
   }

   if (k > 1) {
    return fn(v[m], v[m - 1], m - f);
   }

   return fn(v[i], v[i + 1 > m ? m : i + 1], f - i);

  },

  Bezier: function (v, k) {

   var b = 0;
   var n = v.length - 1;
   var pw = Math.pow;
   var bn = TWEEN.Interpolation.Utils.Bernstein;

   for (var i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    b += pw(1 - k, n - i) * pw(k, i) * v[i] * bn(n, i);
   }

   return b;

  },

  CatmullRom: function (v, k) {

   var m = v.length - 1;
   var f = m * k;
   var i = Math.floor(f);
   var fn = TWEEN.Interpolation.Utils.CatmullRom;

   if (v[0] === v[m]) {

    if (k < 0) {
     i = Math.floor(f = m * (1 + k));
    }

    return fn(v[(i - 1 + m) % m], v[i], v[(i + 1) % m], v[(i + 2) % m], f - i);

   } else {

    if (k < 0) {
     return v[0] - (fn(v[0], v[0], v[1], v[1], -f) - v[0]);
    }

    if (k > 1) {
     return v[m] - (fn(v[m], v[m], v[m - 1], v[m - 1], f - m) - v[m]);
    }

    return fn(v[i ? i - 1 : 0], v[i], v[m < i + 1 ? m : i + 1], v[m < i + 2 ? m : i + 2], f - i);

   }

  },

  Utils: {

   Linear: function (p0, p1, t) {

    return (p1 - p0) * t + p0;

   },

   Bernstein: function (n, i) {

    var fc = TWEEN.Interpolation.Utils.Factorial;

    return fc(n) / fc(i) / fc(n - i);

   },

   Factorial: (function () {

    var a = [1];

    return function (n) {

     var s = 1;

     if (a[n]) {
      return a[n];
     }

     for (var i = n; i > 1; i--) {
      s *= i;
     }

     a[n] = s;
     return s;

    };

   })(),

   CatmullRom: function (p0, p1, p2, p3, t) {

    var v0 = (p2 - p0) * 0.5;
    var v1 = (p3 - p1) * 0.5;
    var t2 = t * t;
    var t3 = t * t2;

    return (2 * p1 - 2 * p2 + v0 + v1) * t3 + (- 3 * p1 + 3 * p2 - 2 * v0 - v1) * t2 + v0 * t + p1;

   }

  }

 };
 TWEEN.version = version;

 return TWEEN;

})));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Locate the user</title>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.115/build/three.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/mrdoob/three.js/master/examples/js/loaders/GLTFLoader.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.tutorialjinni.com/tween.js/18.5.0/Tween.js"></script>











  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    canvas {
      display: block;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>


<script src="js/capture.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```